# Accessing route parameters in Angular 7/8 layout components and services?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, multi-tenant

I have a multitenant application that identifies tenants based on a route parameters called `organization`. I have various portions of the application that need to change behavior based upon the organization passed in through the route parameter, but I'm running into some issues accessing the parameter anywhere other than the component that the router has navigated to.

In multiple areas of my application, I've placed a variant of the following code:

```js
export class OrganizationSidebarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      console.log('[OrganizationSidebarComponent] ID IS ' + params['organization']);
      console.log(params);
    });
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(paramMap => {
      console.log('[OrganizationSidebarComponent] ID from ParamMap: ' + paramMap.get('organization'));
    });
    console.log('[OrganizationSidebarComponent] ID using snapshot paramMap: ' + this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('organization'));
    console.log('[OrganizationSidebarComponent] ID using snapshot params: ' + this.route.snapshot.params.organization);
  }
}
```

However, when the pages are navigated to, the output looks like the following:
[image: Console output]

My routes are setup like so:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'Organization',
    component: OrganizationsLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: ':organization',
        component: OrganizationDashboardComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

In a perfect world, I'd be able to access the values from some injected service so that I have a centralized fetching service that I can leverage to obtain the required information, but I'm simply having issues retrieving the route parameters from anywhere that isn't the component that is being navigated to.

How can I access this information?

Comment: Have a look at this current question in SO. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40219790/angular-2-get-routeparams-in-a-service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to do it in another way, (based on your problem statement) instead of reading the organization in many components and loading data, read that in the app.component as below

add this method in App.component.ts

```
  mergeRouteParams(router: Router): { [key: string]: string } {
    let params = {};
    let route = router.routerState.snapshot.root;
    do {
      params = { ...params, ...route.params };
      route = route.firstChild;
    } while (route);

    return params;
  }
```

then in ngOnInit do this

```
    this.router.events.subscribe((e) => {
      if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        const mergedParams = this.mergeRouteParams(this.router);
        console.log(mergedParams);
      }
    });
```

and of course add `private router: Router` to your constructor

### Working stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-merge-route-params

Url to check [https://angular-merge-route-params.stackblitz.io/dictionary/dict/code](https://angular-1dtfvr.stackblitz.io/dictionary/dict/code)

[image]

### Solution 2

Another way to get all params is using route configuration

```
export const routingConfiguration: ExtraOptions = {
    paramsInheritanceStrategy: 'always',
};

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, routingConfiguration)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

now if you inject `route: ActivatedRoute` in the params or paramsMap you will all params from parents including this child route